# Why updateModel() dont update my model! in MVC ASP.NET for the nested IList<Object>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nested-lists

### Models :

```
public class Category
  {
    [Key]
    public int Categoryid { get; set; }

    [Required , StringLength(50)]
    public string Categoryname { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
  }

  public class SubCategory
  {

    [Key]
    public int SubCategoryid { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public string SubCategoryname { get; set; }
    public int Categoryid { get; set; }

    public SubCategory( string name)
    {
        SubCategoryname = name;
    }

    public SubCategory()
    {          
    }
  }
```

---

### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Category CatModifications, int id, string txtSub, string SubCreate, string SaveAll)
{
  Category Cat = context.Categories.Single(model => model.Categoryid == id);
  UpdateModel(Cat, new string[] { "Categoryname" });

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      // Create Sub
      if (SubCreate != null)
      {
        if (txtSub != "")
        {
          context.SubCategories.Add(new SubCategory(txtSub) { Categoryid = Cat.Categoryid });
          context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Edit");
      }
      if (SaveAll != null)
      {               
        // Edit Sub/Cat
        for (int i = 0; i < Cat.SubCategories.Count; i++)
        {
          UpdateModel(Cat, new string[] { "SubCategories["+i+"].SubCategoryname" });<---------- Here my Model dont update with my subcat
        }
        context.Entry(Cat).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("index");
      }

    }
    return View();
   }
```

---

### view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

  <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Categoryname)<br/>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Categoryname)
  </div>


  <div>
    @if (Model != null && Model.SubCategories != null)
    {
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubCategories)<br/>

      for (int i = 0; i < Model.SubCategories.Count; i++)
       {
         <input type="text" name="SubCategories[@i].SubCategoryname" value="@Model.SubCategories[@i].SubCategoryname"/>
         //@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubCategories[i].SubCategoryname)
         @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteSub", "Categories", new {SubId = Model.SubCategories[i].SubCategoryid}, null)<br/>
       }

    <input type="text" value="" name="txtSub"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Create SubCategory" name="SubCreate"/>
    }
  </div>

  <div>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" name="SaveAll" />
  </div>
}

<div class="Back-Button">
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

-

so! my not nested list proprieties (categoryname) updating well but not my nested list one (subcategories[i]subcategoryname) ... any one know why or if i did somting wrong here ? ty a lot ...

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `public virtual IList<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }` in constructor

Comment: hummm i added it but have no result :S

Comment: check if posted CatModifications parameter is correct (Without UpdateModel) and use commented EditoFor

Comment: did you put @model type declaration in the view ?

Comment: yep ... my controller receive all the that that is needed .... it just the updatemodel that doest work ...

Comment: Yeah it working ... but my goal is to update only some stuf particulaly

Answer (score -1):

```
<input name="SubCategories[@i].SubCategoryname" value="@Model.SubCategories[@i].SubCategoryname"/>
```

ok the way im binding the data is workiing .... the proof :

the Request.Form.allkeys.tolist = Categoryname,SubCategories[0].SubCategoryname,txtSub,SaveAll

with all the good value in it ....

it just when im doing the updatemodel that not working .....

i got an category with the changes (CatModifications)  witout id in it ...
and i go a cat witout the changes (Cat ) but with teh id in it

so i want to update "Cat" with the change of CatModifications

UpdateModel(Cat, new string[] { "SubCategories["+i+"].SubCategoryname" , "Categoryname" })

Categoryname work but not SubCategories["+i+"].SubCategoryname... and i know the value are in it .... so why it not updating it .....

Comment: This is not an answer so delete it. Your code shows a lack of understanding of the basics of MVC's model binding features. To render the sub category name use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubCategories[i].SubCategoryname)`. You do not need to call `UpdateModel`. The model is already bound and updated based on you views controls! Your not rendering controls for `Categoryid` or the `SubCategories.SubCategoryid`'s so they will always be zero on postback.